# Looping through dictionary in python

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AOMk.png)

Enclosed is a copy of a question I am trying to answer. (Its not homework btw, just from a programming ebook).

So, in the first instance, I created the dictionary.

```
fridge ={ "steak" : "it is so yum!" , \
  "Pizza" : "it is even yummier!" , \
  "eggs": "always handy in a pinch" , \
  "ice cream": "a tasty treat for when I work hard" , \
  "butter" : "always useful for spreading on toast" \
  }
```

Have to admit, maybe it has been the way the text has been worded, by the sentence:

"**Then create a name that refers to a string containing the name of a food, call the name food_sought**

badly confused me.

I thought this meant:

create a variable called food_sought, make it equal to any of the keys within the fridge dictionary.... then use a for loop to see if there is a match within the dictionary.

so....

```
    food_sought = "steak"
for food_sought in fridge:
    if food_sought !=steak:
        print ("there has not been a match!")
```

Whenever I run the code however, I am told:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 2, in 
    if food_sought ==steak:
NameError: name 'steak' is not defined

Comment: The question is rather hard to understand, it's true. In particular, one of the main reasons to use a dictionary in the first place is that you don't need to loop through in order to get a value for a key.

Comment: `if food_sought !=steak:` does not mean `if food_sought !="steak":` your error is saying for the prior, you have the variable `steak` which is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`steak` in this case would be a variable.

What it looks like you're asking for is:

`food_sought != 'steak'`

but what you probably want is

`key != food_sought`

See below

If you want the value you can use `items()` in python3 or `iteritems()` in python 2

```
food_sought = 'steak'
for key, value in fridge.items():
    if key != food_sought:
        print("Not the key we're looking for...")
    print(key)    # the key, ie "steak'
    print(value)  # the value, ie "it is so yum!" -- I agree
```

Beef it's what's for dinner.

Comment: That is why I am somewhat surprised by the question, because I have used fridge.keys/fridge.values as appropriate to get the necessary info,

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can iter over a dictionary using a for loop like you want hope it helps you better understand :)

```
fridge ={ "steak" : "it is so yum!" , \
  "Pizza" : "it is even yummier!" , \
  "eggs": "always handy in a pinch" , \
  "ice cream": "a tasty treat for when I work hard" , \
  "butter" : "always useful for spreading on toast" \
  }

food_sought = "steak"

for key, value in fridge.items():
  if(key == food_sought):
    print(key, 'corresponds to', value)
  else:
    print ("There has not been a match!")
```

**Output: (note dictionaries are not ordered)**

```
There has not been a match!
There has not been a match!
There has not been a match!
There has not been a match!
steak corresponds to it is so yum!
```

Try it [here](https://repl.it/E7zb/0)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that steak is a variable, which you haven´t defined. 
When you write `food_sought!=steak` you are comparing the value of two variables, but variable **steak** is not defined.

Your first line of code is wrongly assigning `food_sought="steak"`, it should be assigning `steak='steak'`. That way your code would work:

```
steak = "steak"
for food_sought in fridge:
    if food_sought != steak:
        print ("there has not been a match!")
```

Having said this, how you have written the code is not the best/nicest way of doing, although it works. There is no need of defining the variable `steak`, you can compare the `food_sought` variable directly against the string `'steak'`.
The code would look like this:

```
for food_sought in fridge:
    if food_sought != 'steak':
        print ("there has not been a match!")
```